# Is there a way in Xamarin to avoid command repetition?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have 10 Xamarin Pages/Views, there's one command/code block that's repeated in the code-behind for all of them. And it does the same thing on all the pages, just pop the stack until you reach the root.

I have tried extending the base class (ContentPage) to make a custom class but got an error since it was a partial class?

Error Message :

```
"Partial declarations of 'TestPage' must not specify different base classes"
```

Is there a way to avoid rewriting the same Method in all 10 classes? Also, I'm using Xamarin with Prism

Comment: if you change the base class of the page in the code behind you need to also update the base class in the XAML

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a base page with xaml, you could use a base page.

BasePage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="App2.BasePage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
mc:Ignorable="d" />
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<app2:BasePage
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:app2="clr-namespace:App2"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<app2:BasePage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Wellcome to MainPage!!!" />
    </StackLayout>
</app2:BasePage.Content>

</app2:BasePage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class MainPage : BasePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```